# Why do Shankaracharya and Ramanujacharya in their Gita Bhasya 18.41 say that Sudras are Tamasik?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, samkhya

It might indeed be true that a person who serves society has less wisdom than a Brahmana who studies Vedas + Vedanta but that doesn't mean his nature is decided before his conduct is checked. Vidura was a Sudra and Ashwatthama a Bramhana yet we could say Vidura wasn't Tamasic and Aswatthama was Demonic. Lord Shiva does say that A Sudra if controls senses is as worshippable as a Brahmana but how can we predecide that certain group of people are Tamsik? And Sudras are supposed to work for society so they can't be lazy, idle etc. For Hindu theory of knowledge, observation and reason are the primary sources. We can observe on a daily basis Brahmins who are grossly Tamasic and Sudras that are extremely Sattvic. I did refer Prof Radhakrishnan, Gita Press, Swami Ranganathananda and Swami Mukundananda Commentaries also for these verses.

Edit :

Also in Bhagavata we see verses like

> Being always very clean, being free from duplicity,not stealing,
> always speaking the truth are natural symptoms of Sudras (SB 7.11.24)
>
> Nonviolence, truthfulness, honesty, desire for the happiness and
> welfare of all others and freedom from lust, anger and greed
> constitute duties for all members of society.(SB 11.17.21)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123105/discussion-on-question-by-sethu-srivatsa-koduru-why-do-shankaracharya-and-ramanu).

Comment: There are 4 varnas based upon 3 gunas and Nirgunata, Nirguna Brahmin, Satva Kshatriyas, Rajas Vaishya and Tamas Shudra, but this is implemented by Manu during Treta descent, right now we are in ascent for 12000 years during https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Aquarius, http://www.dwapara-yuga.org ascent towards Satyuga and children are more evolved than their parents. In Satyuga their is only one varna of Hansa or Brahmins, hence so much intermixing between Hindus and non-Hindus, research, science etc., Sorting based on Varna will happen in Treta descent which will start around 14000 AD.

Comment: When polaris is Vega, then alone age of Leo or age of Kings and Varna system, writing reciting Vedas, Easternization and descent for 12000 years start. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/539376492842065535/ This is repeated 1000 times which are number of yugas.